# jQuery onclick escape key event

Tags: jquery

i'm using jQuery UI to display a dialog box. i have disabled the selection of page background using a div which acts as a background window with some opacity. the dialog box has a close button so that it gets closed onclick of the button and at the same time the background window is hidden. now, when i press the escape key then the dialog box gets closed but the background remains displayed. How can i close the background as well onclick of escape key.

```
$("#open").click(function(){
    $(".dialog").dialog("open");
     $(".bg-opacity").fadeIn();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $(".dialog").dialog("close");
     $(".bg-opacity").fadeOut();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Catch the escape key keydown and call the close click function. Try this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#close").click()
    }   
});
```

Edit: Whilst it's possible to capture escape on the whole document, as my example did initially, it would be better to capture escape for just the dialog box when it is open, to prevent continually capturing escape on the whole document.

```
$(NAME_OF_POPUP_DIALOG).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $("#close").click()
    }   
});
```

This may require you to add the `tabindex="0"` attribute to the dialog div, to allow it to have focus and detect the keydown.

Answer (score 0):

try, catch escape and close dialog:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(".dialog").dialog("close");
        $(".bg-opacity").fadeOut();
    }   
});
```